# Copy file from Windows to Linux server by using jump server

Tags: linux, windows, scp

I have Windows machine and Linux 1 and 2 servers.

Windows machine doesn't have a direct access to Linux 2 server. I need to go via Linux 1.

How can I copy files from Windows Machine to Linux 2 server directly?

Answer (score 0):

I would take the Putty and would create a tunnel from windows to linux 1 through linux 2.

[putty-session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTJXw.jpg)

[putty-tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMcU2.jpg)

When you start the session to linux2 it opens a tunnel to linux1.

Open a WinSCP on your Windows and open session like this:

linux1user@127.0.0.1:40022

[winscp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0AoI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP SFTP client supports tunneling though other SSH server natively.

See the [Tunnel page of its Advanced site settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel).

[image]

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

For other clients, you can setup the tunnel using PuTTY and connect though it.

See WinSCP guide for [tunneling SFTP/SCP session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty).